# How to specify outgoing http call timeout in Twilio

Tags: .net, twilio

I'm using `TwilioRestClient` from .NET Twilio.API 3.4.1.0. I need to specify timeout when calling to `SendSmsMessage()` but it looks like there is no suitable overload. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to be clear, you want to specify the HTTP timeout?  I don't think you can do this via the library so it its something you absolutely need, you will probably have to just make the API request via RestSharp or HttpWebRequest (or HttpClient of you are using .NET 4 or newer).

Can I ask why you need to set the timeout?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I send SMS from my WCF service and need to be sure HTTP timeout is less than timeout of my service call.